# SAP Cloud Foundry Multitenancy with Managed Application Router

Tags: sapui5, multi-tenant, sap-cloud-foundry

I'm trying to add multitenancy to my SAPUI5 Fiori applications which used Managed Application Router in SAP Cloud Foundry.

Is there a way to subscribe to a sapui5 application that uses Managed Application Router in provider sub-account from a tenant sub-account?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment as far as I know.

To be able to have true Multitenancy, each tenants identity validation must be seperated. And this is only possible with standalone approuter which has
an environment variable called 'TENANT_HOST_PATTERN' which is a regex pattern.
Approuter uses this regex pattern to isolate each tenants login flow.

BTW : If you have any conceptual questions about multitenancy in SAP BTP Cloud Foundry I would strongly reccomend to read [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/08/20/getting-your-head-into-cloud-application-programming-model-multitenancy/)

Best,